# How can I stop a dialog window from getting hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

If I create a class derived from System.Windows.Window and show it with ShowDialog it appears above the main window as expected, and the main window is disabled.
However it is possible to put both windows behind other applications, and then just bring the main window back. This just leaves a single window which appears to have crashed, and can be confusing.

Is it possible to ensure that the dialog window is always displayed if the main window is shown? The MessageBox.Show dialog has no such problems

**Update:**

A test dialog is defined as

```
public partial class MyDialog : Window
{
    public MyDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and called using

```
    MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
    d.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Do you use Form::ShowDialog(IWin32Window) method? Dialog with owner window should behave as you expect.

Comment: I'm not using Forms, its a System.Windows.Window, and ShowDialog does not take any parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to set the Owner property.

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
d.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;//or your owning window
d.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I'm using `PopupWindowAction` in my WPF Application. Setting the _owner_ to the _current main window_ was the key for getting the described behavior we know from _Windows MessageBox_. (Thanks, I've searched for an hour...!)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the dialog window is always displayed if the main window is shown, add handler to main form visibility changed event to set `TopMost` true or false to child form according to main visibility

```
ChildForm frmDLg = null;
public MainForm()
{
    this.VisibleChanged += MainFrmVisibleChanged;
}

private void LoadDialogForm()
{
    try {
        if (frmDLg == null || frmDLg.IsDisposed) {
            frmDLg = new ChildForm();
        }
        frmDLg.ShowDialog();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Handle exception
    }
}

private void MainFrmVisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (frmDLg != null && !frmDLg.IsDisposed) {
        frmDLg.TopMost = this.Visible;
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
public override bool Visible
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                // Insert my code
                if (frmDLg != null && !frmDLg.IsDisposed)
                {
                    frmDLg.TopMost = this.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
```

The last cure i can think is to use a timer with user32 dll getforegroundwindow to check if main form is visible.

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Window not a Form, and that does not have a VisibleChanged events property. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: Sorry i can't find System.Windows.Window in dot net 3.5, any way if you can find Window.Visible property so try to override it so instead my `MainFrmVisibleChanged` use the set of Visible property check update up there

Comment: Details are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx
Thanks for the suggestions, but settings the owner resolves the problem for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work as you want

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Activated += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Activated);
    }

    void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m == null)
            return;

        m.Activate();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m = new MyDialog();
        m.ShowDialog();
    }
    MyDialog m;
```